# Removing "gwendall:autoform-i18n" crashes Meteor app, causes "Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element"

Tags: meteor, packaging

It's been a thorn in my side for some time. I'm trying to remove `gwendall:autoform-i18n` package from Meteor 1.6. Removing it prevents the root id from presenting, and stops the page loading. Works fine with it in. react-router is V3.

Console reports: `"Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element"` and the `render-root` element is, in fact, missing from the tree.

How do I remove it properly?

**main.html** contains

```
<body>
  <div id="render-root"></div>
</body>
```

**main.jsx** just loads

```
import '/imports/startup/client/routes.jsx'
```

**routes.jsx**

```
Meteor.startup(()=>{

let elem = document.getElementById('render-root')

let router = (
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
    <Route path="/"               component={ Landing } />
    <Route path="/"               component={ App }>
        <IndexRoute                    component={ Menu } />
        <Route path="menu"             component={ Menu } />
        <Route path="category/:name"   component={ CategoryPage } />
        <Route path="*"                component={ PageNotFound }/>
    </Route>
</Router> )

render( router, elem )

}
```

Comment: Are there any console errors? What other components are there?

Comment: Yes, just that one in the title.